# WPF DataBinding with Constructor

Tags: wpf, generics, data-binding, collections, listbox

(For this example) ListBox l is bound to CustomObjectCollection c.

Does l call c's Constructor?

What if c is a Generic Object?

`**In XAML (1)**`
`<ListBox Content={Binding CustomObjectCollection}/>`

`**In Codebehind**`
`CustomObjectCollection<MyClass> c;`
`**In XAML (2)**`
`<ListBox Content={Binding CustomObjectCollection}/>`

Suppose in `c`, I populate the collection(dynamically, using the constructor)
Which binding would call the constructor?

Sorry if this is unclear, I have no idea how to explain it.

Comment: This question is not very clear. What are you trying to accomplish? Can you post your XAML/code-behind?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should bind to a property. If the source object needs to be constructed, then it has to be done in the code behind.

```
<ListBox ItemsSource={Binding ListSource} />
```

```
//Codebehind
class MyControl : UserControl {
    public CustomObjectCollection ListSource {get; private set;}

    public MyControl() {
      ListSource  = new CustomObjectCollection (/*arguments*/);
      InitializeComponent();
      DataContext = this;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A couple things:

1. You can only bind to public properties. It appears you have `c` declared as a member variable, but not a property. So this binding will not succeed.
2. There is no way to bind using a `Content` property on `ListBox`. I think what you are trying to do is better accomplished using the [`ItemsSource`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemssource(VS.95).aspx) property. Check out the example linked on MSDN; that should get you started.